# exporting csv file in .Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, export

I am trying to fix an issue in my code.  ASP.Net MVC I am developing for functionality to export data into a CSV file.  The export method works, allowing to created the Excel spreadsheet based on the filter criteria I have, but the last row is missing columns near the end.  For example, user selects filter criteria and 100 rows are exportable, they are exported into Excel, but are misssing the last 5 or so columns on the 100th row.  Below is the method I am working on :

```
public void Export(string filterExp = null)
    {
        var workingListModel = SessionManager.GetSessionValue("LastWorkingListModel") as GridViewCustomBindingGetDataRowCountArgs;
        var exportData = ServiceLocator.WorkingListGridSvc.GetWorkingListExportData(workingListModel);

        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        var writer = new CsvWriter(new StreamWriter(memoryStream));
        writer.WriteRecords(exportData);

        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=WorkingList.csv");
        Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        Response.Write(new StreamReader(memoryStream).ReadToEnd());
        Response.End();
    }
```

If anyone has some feedback to help me with this issue or a better structure for this method, please let me know.

Comment: Is this a controller method?  Where's the code for CsvWriter?  Are there commas in your data?

Comment: writer is the variable object for CSVWriter.  And yes, this is  a method on it's controller.